# JWT token encryption and transferring in http get

Tags: java, security, single-sign-on, jwt

I'd like to validate one security approach that we'd like to use.
We have a two applications and we'd like to pass data using jwt token (make redirect from one pllication to another + pass sensitive information in token).

For this purpose we  created JWTSigner with shared secret and sign all claims.

```
JWTSigner signer = new JWTSigner(secret);
return signer.sign(claims);
```

As per my understanding preferable we need additionally encrypt this information as signing pervent us only from tampering this info.

The question is whether it's secure enough to pass this token as parameter in url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

If done right, yes, it is safe -- as only your applications will be able to issue valid tokens. If done wrong, it is worthless.

How to do it right (TM):

- The payload in JWT is not generally encrypted; it can be read by third parties after base64-decoding. Signing it prevents tampering, but not disclosure.
- JWT has an "alg" field that can be used to specify the encryption algorithm used. It is [attacker-friendly](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/03/31/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/): do not trust its contents.
- Make yourself immune to replay attacks, for example by using and verifying a request counter or a time-stamp.
- Use strong encryption. Public-key encryption has the advantage of allowing each endpoint to verify the other, even without knowing the other's private key; but symmetric encryption is also an option.
- Protect your secret keys. Use different keys for testing and deployment, and never check keys into source-control.

Comment: One clarification for "Use strong encryption" item. Id token going to be passed using http get the only option is possible using symmetric key. Am I right ?

Comment: No - signing can be done with any algorithm supported by your JWT implementation, regardless of what claims (ID, ...) you are signing. One of the optional algorithms is RSA (public key), and since you mention Java, a quick search shows it is supported by http://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt - I have not used it personally.